# How to retain variable information in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to convert a text adventure originally made in vanilla Python to a Tkinter format. My attempt at this was to create a dictionary that would be updated whenever information was entered, but the dictionary information isn't saving and seems to revert back to an empty dict every time.

How would I do this ? Apologies if the question is unclear, I am very new to Tkinter and have been struggling with this for a long time.

Here is my code, all it needs to do is figure out if the player wants to activate the tutorial :

```
from tkinter import *

# Storage    
game_text = {}    
cmd = {}    
root = Tk()

# Configuration    
root.geometry ("1000x1000")
root.title("A New Dawn")    
icon = PhotoImage(file = "C:/Users/gwynn/Desktop/wcnd_icon.png")    
root.iconphoto(False, icon)    
root.configure(bg="#006644")

# Parsers    
def parse(tag, line):
    game_text[tag] = Text(root, width = 200, height = 1)    
    game_text[tag].insert(INSERT, line)    
    game_text[tag].pack()    
    game_text[tag].tag_add(tag, '1.0', 'end')    
    game_text[tag].tag_config(tag, background = "#006644", foreground = "#8cd98c")
    
def cmd_parse(cmd_box):    
    cmd['cmd'] = cmd_box.widget.get()    
    cmd['cmd'] = cmd['cmd'].lower()        
    print(cmd['cmd'])       

# The Game    
parse('tutorial', "Welcome to WC : A New Dawn ! Before we begin - would you like to activate the tutorial ? [Y/N]")    
cmd_box = Entry(root, background = '#096', foreground = "#b3e6b3", width = 200, border = 3)    
cmd_box.pack()    
cmd_box.bind("<Return>", cmd_parse)    
print(cmd)

if 'cmd' in list(cmd):    
    if cmd['cmd'] == "y":        
        parse('tutorial_y', "Excellent ! The tutorial has been activated.")                        
    elif cmd['cmd'] == "n":
        parse('tutorial_n', "Excellent ! The tutorial has been deactivated.")            

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "every time"? Every time the information is updated?

Comment: Yes, every time I enter information into the cmd_box and then press return, it doesn't have the intended result, and through print() I have figured out it's because the dict is still empty.

Comment: The bindings won't work until you start the main loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to manage cmd conditions before the user has even had the chance to type. You have to move your conditions (or call a function of your conditions) after you have actually retrieved the typed data.

```
def cmd_parse(event): 
    cmd = event.widget.get().lower() 
    
    if cmd == "y":        
        parse('tutorial_y', "Excellent ! The tutorial has been activated.")                        
    elif cmd == "n":
        parse('tutorial_n', "Excellent ! The tutorial has been deactivated.")
```

Comment: This helped, thank you very much. So does that mean you recommend making individual functions for each decision made in the game ? like cmd_tutorial , cmd_charactercreate , cmd_battle , etc ?